# Missing header files while installing packages using pip

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, pip

I was trying to get mysql working with django. Installing the required bindings in an virtualenv using pip generates an error.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

The package gets downloaded but I get the following error saying a header file my_config.h is missing.

```
    (django)[jmathews@localhost pollsys]$ pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/build/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python

Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
    _mysql.c:44:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
     #include "my_config.h"
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Qa0mhq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -fPIC -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1

_mysql.c:44:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory

 #include "my_config.h"

                       ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Qa0mhq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/jmathews/.virtualenvs/django/build/MySQL-python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jmathews/.pip/pip.log
```

The following packages were installed and updated.

```
yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

I also ran

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
```

The problem persists. Is the problem with the package or any missing dependencies?

Comment: `yum install mysql-devel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the header files for mysql library.
I don't know for your distrib, on Ubuntu the package name is `libmysqlclient-dev`.

By the way, if starting a new project, I would recommend PostgreSQL over MySQL, because support for MySQL is uncertain at best.

**edit:** turns out things change, there are now [bindings for Python 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient)

Comment: Yes, installing the yum counterpart mysql-devel solved the problem. I am running MySQL because my project involves many read operations and PostgreSQL, I learnt is slower with read operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum info mysql-devel
```

If it's not installed, install it

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Now try

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing mysql-dev solved my problem as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

and then

`pip install MySQL-python`